# "Kitchen list" command fails with "Could not load the 'ssh' transport from the load path"

Tags: ruby, ssh, chef-infra, test-kitchen, kitchen-dokken

I'm trying to add a Test Kitchen to a Chef cookbook but am getting the error "Could not load the 'ssh' transport from the load path".

I have previously set up a Test Kitchen following the exact same steps without issue, but that was on a different machine.

I've tried running

```
gem install net-ssh
```

But that doesn't seem to fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

I ran

```
gem list
```

Which gave the output

```
..
net-ssh (2.10.0.beta2, 2.9.2)
..
```

I then issued the command:

```
gem uninstall net-ssh 2.10.9.beta2
```

And got the output:

```
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. net-ssh-2.10.0.beta2
 2. net-ssh-2.9.2
 3. All versions
```

Whereupon I selected option 1, the gem was removed and then running

```
kitchen list
```

Worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem for [Java SE Chef cookbook](https://github.com/dhoer/chef-java_se) on Travis-CI with:

```
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.10.0
chef-client version: 12.6.0
berks version: 4.0.1
kitchen version: 1.5.0
```

Throwing this:

```
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.5.0)
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ClientError
>>>>>> Message: Could not load the 'ssh' transport from the load path. Please ensure that your transport is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using Bundler.
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

I had to switch to Dokken to get it to work:
https://github.com/someara/kitchen-dokken

---

To fix:

Update .travis.yml to install kitchen-dokken:

`/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/chef gem install kitchen-dokken`

And update .kitchen.docker.yml with:

```
transport:
  name: dokken

provisioner:
  name: dokken

verifier:
  root_path: '/opt/verifier'
  sudo: false

driver:
  name: dokken
```